# Should the community wiki status be removed from this question?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Something or other brought [this old thread to my attention recently,](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/21292/3188) which made me notice that [it had been algorithmically converted to community wiki less than a month before that functionality was disabled](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/21292/3188).  Anyway, I flagged it for moderator attention, as it doesn't strike me as a particularly collaborative effort (only one of the question's edits is really substantiall) and I generally dislike community wiki after having put up with its being triggered by a very imperfect algorithm over at my "home" Stack Exchange site for a few years.

Anyway, one of the friendly neighborhood moderators responded to my flag by requesting that I pose the question on meta to see what the community thinks.

So, what do you think?

[Yes or no to removing the community wiki status on the question in question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/21292/3188)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any reason to leave that as Community Wiki so I've removed that from the question and all the answers.  (I had to do that one post at a time, so if I managed to miss any, please flag pointing it out and we'll get it fixed.)

Comment: I recently saw a quite detailed explanation on how to handle these matters at MSO: [How to decide whether to un-wiki questions/answers posted in rep-denial era](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288022/839601)

Comment: @gnat thanks for the pointer.